# iOS / iPhones in Enterprise: Deployment of App Store apps in batch

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, enterprise

In my organization, we wish to install several App Store apps for a large number of our employees. The apps are Apple's Apps in the App store, such as KeyNote and Pages.

The current setup is to manually download the apps via the App Store in each device, which consumes lot's of internet bandwidth and time.

Is there a better alternative to deploy App Store apps to a large number of user's without having to download the apps again for each device?

P.S I do have the IMEI, Serial Number and each user's Apple IDs.

Comment: I found that Apple has a Caching Server as part of the OS X Server which does as I needed, however we will not be using OS X Server in our organization, is there any different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the apps were purchased through the Volume Purchase Program, you can install them using Apple Configurator. Add the VPP codes, connect the devices and click install. Alternatively if the apps are free you can simply drag the app into the app list and install it that way.

For more information regarding this, see this Apple KB article:

- [Apple Configurator: Using Volume Purchase Program (VPP) Redemption Codes](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5188)

Otherwise as you mentioned the Caching Server in OS X Server would cache a copy of the app so that downloads would come from your server instead of over the internet.